# Initialize Viewpager views while dragging

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

I have a view pager for selecting an avatar. this view pager shows 3 page at a time, how ever when dragging the view pager a few pages over, incoming views are not initialized until i stop dragging. how do i fix this?

Here is how I set the padding to show multiple pages

```
setClipToPadding(false); // must be false so left and right pages will be always visible.
float visiblePages = 3;
post(() -> { // set padding to get visible pages.
    int padding = Math.round(getWidth() * (1f - 1f / visiblePages) / 2f);
    int paddingLeft = Math.max(getPaddingLeft(), padding);
    int paddingRight = Math.max(getPaddingRight(), padding);
    setPadding(paddingLeft, getPaddingTop(), paddingRight, getPaddingBottom());
});
```

I need to call a method to trigger the initialization of views while dragging, but I don't know what to call.

I tried to do this using PageTransformer and call `populate` using reflection but it didn't work

```
@Override
public void transformPage(@NonNull View page, float position) {
    float distance = Math.abs(position - (visiblePages - 1f) / 2f); // actual distance from center.

    if(distance > 1 || distance < 1) { 
        populate(); // calling populate using reflection causes infinite loop.
    }
}
```

---

Note that setting offset page limit to maximum is not the solution i want. I need something efficient like recyclerView.

I also use page transformer to zoom selected avatar in center.